# How to create AWS default VPC through aws-java-sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, cloud

I want to create default VPC with all default components(i.e default security group,internet gateway) and components that are needed for an instance launched inside this VPC to communicate to external world say through ssh. I can create such VPCthrough AWS VPC console keeping default option selected but I want to do it through java code using aws-java-sdk. 
I tried this code

```
private static void createVpc()
{
        System.out.println("Creating VPC.....\n");
        CreateVpcRequest newVPC = new CreateVpcRequest();
        String cidrBlock = "10.0.0.0/28";
        newVPC.setCidrBlock(cidrBlock);

        CreateVpcResult res = ec2.createVpc(newVPC);

        Vpc vp = res.getVpc();

        vp.setIsDefault(true);
        String vpcId = vp.getVpcId();
        System.out.println("Created VPC"+vpcId);
        //deleteVpc("vpc-c80418aa");

    }
```

but it creates VPC and no other associated components.
Please tell what else I need to do or provide sample code steps to build VPC with other components.

Comment: Why do you want to create VPC in code? CloudFormation may be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible. A default VPC is created by *default* by AWS when you create your account. 
In addition, old active account cannot have default VPC at all...

So either build a cloud formation template or use Java to build all required elements.

-R

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to mark as answered to assist other people.